# Idempotents in Green J classes

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

I recently read this article [*Syntactic semigroups*](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~jep/PDF/HandBook.pdf). In page $8$, he speaks about a J class having an idempotent is called *regular*:

> A $\mathcal J$-class containing an idempotent is called *regular*. One can show that in a regular $\mathcal J$-class, every $\mathcal R$-class and every $\mathcal L$-class contains an idempotent.

As all Green J classes make a partition for given semigroup $S$, so if we accept $S$ has idempotents so they are included in some J classes. My question is:

> Is there any reference that, I can find if J classes have just **one** idempotent inside or not? In fact, how can one find out, in a given semigroup (say, finite semigroup), whether a J class cannot have two idempotents?

Thank you for your time and the hints or any references.

Comment: Perhaps, the most interesting things around this are finitely generated simple and bisimple semigroups -- you may find quite a lot of beautiful papers by Byleen about this

Comment: @Victor: Thanks for your suggestion. I follow the Byleen's papers now.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to http://math.stackexchange.com since it is not a research question.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: There are few ones who are interested doing semigroups as I have seen up to now and moreover I am working on quasicommutative semigroups. And this question came to my mind and ask it here. Anyway, if they decide to make this migrated, That'll be Ok. :-) Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any regular $J$-class with a joined zero is a 0-simple semigroup. So your question is reduced to the following: who many idempotents has  a 0-simple semigroup? In particular, if $S$ is finite, a $J$-class (with 0) is completely 0-simple semigroup, so it has just one idempotent $\ne 0$ iff it is a group.

Moreover, if a  0-simple semigroup $S$ with 1 has no other idempotents, then it is a group with 0.

*Proof:* Let $G$ be its subgroup of invertible elements. For every $a\in S\setminus 0$ there are such $x,y\in S$ that $xay=1$. Then $(ayx)^2=ayx$ whence $ayx=1$. Since $xay=ayx=1$, hence $x\in G$. But then $a=x^{-1}y^{-1}\in G$, i.e. $S=G\cup 0$.

Comment: I guess, finiteness of $S$ is not that important -- we anyway will have $J^0$ a completely $0$-simple semigroup -- we do have a minimal idempotent

Comment: @Victor "we anyway will have $J^0$ a completely 0-simple semigroup" - what about 0-simple semigroups wich are not completely 0-simple?

Comment: Well, in our setting, when $J^0$ has only two idempotents, we do have a minimal idempotent

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you mean, I didn't read carefully what you wrote in the first paragraph

Comment: @Victor OK, nothing.